# What is the Kelly chip?

Tags: hardware, amiga, chip, amiga-3000

The [Amiga 3000+ DevCon](http://www.thule.no/haynie/research/a3000p/docs/a3000p.pdf) 1991 notes says:

> On the A3000+, these resources include the Amiga "Pandora" chip set
>   (Alice, Lisa, **Kelly**, and Paula),

However, a Kelly chip is not part of the official released AA chipset (Pandora being the development codename for AA). What is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question should rather be: "What could it have been?" - It never made it into an existing machine. According to some Internet lore, Kelly would have been the A3000+'s/AA3000's RAMDAC (digital video memory to analog RGB converter chip) that Commodore was initially planning to develop themselves.

According to the same lore, during the development of Kelly, Commodore encountered a jungle of already existing patented technology that they would have had to navigate that it was decided to use an already existing 3PP (Analog Devices ADV7120KP30) off-the-shelf circuit instead.

Here's a reference: http://obligement.free.fr/articles/chipsetamiga.php#kelly